# Extracting RAR with JunRAR

Tags: java, rar

I have a rar archive which I want to extract to the temporary folder through JunRAR, I initialize Archive by the path which consists folder and needed rar archive, then I'm trying through FileHandler extract archive, but when I'm checking fileName it shows me folder name and data which he contains but no archive. Need yours recommendation on how to solve it.

The path to file is **/home/user/Documents/test.rar**

Folder **/home/user/Documents/** consist :
**TestFolder** with files in
**test.rar**

```
    File file = new File(dir);
    Path tempDirWithPrefix = Files.createTempDirectory(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
    LOG.info(tempDirWithPrefix.toAbsolutePath().toString());

    Archive archive = null;
    if(file.getAbsoluteFile().getName().endsWith(".rar") && !file.isDirectory()){
        archive = new Archive(new FileVolumeManager(file));
    }

    if (archive.isEncrypted()) {
        archive.close();
        throw new RarException(new Exception("Archive is encrypted and cannot be extracted"), rarEncryptedException);
    }

    for (FileHeader fh : archive.getFileHeaders()) {
            LOG.info("Extracting file: " + fh.getFileNameString());
    }
```

Comment: @Akceptor yes, of course, duplicate 8 years ago question ... with old library and problem solve (snippet) which not found ...

Comment: Sure but there might be some alternative libraries mentioned. As for your question I've tried downloading https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.junrar/junrar/0.7 and running your example against a simple rar archive and it ended with 
WARNING: exception in archive constructor maybe file is encrypted or currupt
com.github.junrar.exception.RarException: badRarArchive could ypu please attach your archive or say be more specific about the version of old library?

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко I was able to find the snippet in an older commit on that repo, and I've updated the answer in that duplicate.

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко created an archive using RAR4 format and it works with no issue using your example. Prints C:\Users\akceptor\AppData\Local\Temp\7174023157379502250800613770845137
Extracting file: Python\.classpath
Extracting file: Python\.gitignore

Comment: @Mike thanks for update snippet, the problem is solved.